# Leaflet map popup bound to polygons showing geodesicArea only shows area of most recently drawn polygon

Tags: leaflet

I have a leaflet map with popups bound to polygons. On clicking the polygons the pop up only shows the area of the most recently drawn polygon. I thought this was because of the use of 'draw:created' and changed to 'click' but this stops the popup appearing. Original code is as follows:

```
var polygons = new L.featureGroup();
map.on('draw:created', function(e) {
         var type = e.layerType,
            layer = e.layer;
         if (type === 'polygon') {
            polygons.addLayer(layer);
            var seeArea = L.GeometryUtil.geodesicArea(layer.getLatLngs()[0]);
            drawnItems.bindPopup('area is '+ (seeArea*0.000247105).toFixed(2) +' acres');
         }
      }
);
```

Comment: On each drawn polygon you are binding popup to `drawnItems` layer instead of newly created `layer` polygon. It should be `layer.bindPopup(....`.

Comment: Many thanks that solves it.